# Laravel Blade Syntax @yeild('content') not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

i know this is very basic and silly question but i am trying from last 2 days but not figure out where my mistake is i search everywhere but still not figure out. I am new to laravel and learning from tutorials where i am using blade syntax .

Web.php

```
Route::get('about','makeController@FunFun');
```

makeController.php

```
 class makeController extends Controller
{
public function FunFun(){
    $first = 'Muhammad';
    $last = 'Uzair Warsi';
    return view('pages.app',compact('first'));
}}
```

app.blade.php

```
@extends('pages.funview')

@section('content')

<h1>my name is : {{$first}}</h1>

@stop
```

funview.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<html>
<title>HTML Tutorial</title>
<body>

<h1>this is from funview page</h1>

    @yeild('content')


</body>
</html>
```

the problem is the localhost loads all the things title heading and also print @yeild('content') and not the content of the blade part.

Comment: did you label incorrectly in your post or does your app.blade contain a view and funview contains the template? That's backwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
@yield('content')
```

Not `@yeild`

For more info on Blade and the syntax check: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#template-inheritance

Comment: i can't believe i am making this silly spell mistake. btw thankyou so much

Comment: Hehe np, check if your IDE has a plugin available for blade syntax

Comment: i am using sublime right now and in sublime i dont find blade syntax so i need to make one that is why i am moving to phpstorm

Comment: Make sure you have the package installer and search for `Laravel Blade`, might need a restart to work properly.

Comment: Oh God! Thank you, just saved me a lot of time!